# Refresh WooCommerce Mini-cart via ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm adding items to the cart via a custom plugin and everything works as i need it to, however the mini cart does not update and i can't seem to trigger a refresh.
Here is a piece of my code for reference:

```
javascript: jQuery.ajax({

        url: '/result/',

        data:{post_title:title, post_content:detail,price:price,quantity:quantity},

        success:function (data_rdx) {

            jQuery(".fr-loading").hide();



            if(data_rdx=='fail') {

                alert("Error, Please Try Again");

            } else {

                jQuery(".orb_custom").html(data_rdx);

                //trigger mini-cart refresh
                alert('Cart Updated');

            }

        }});
```

I've tried adding a small ajax post with `wc-ajax=get_refreshed_fragments` but it doesn't seem to work. What would be the easiest way to trigger a refresh?

Thank you.

Comment: `ajax.reload()`? - https://datatables.net/reference/api/ajax.reload() or you could just use `window.location.reload();`

Comment: This works but it's not ideal. The users need to go through 5 steps before they can add products to the cart. Is there a way to use the existing 'get_refreshed_fragments' function via ajax? or possibly a refresh cart button? Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

```
jQuery(document.body).trigger('wc_fragment_refresh');
```