# Woocommerce Blocks: Mini-cart does not reload when adding product to cart via StoreAPI

Tags: woocommerce, gutenberg-blocks

The Mini-Cart Block I used in the block theme is not refreshing its contents after I add the product to the cart using StoreAPI from the custom block I made using @wordpress/create-block. Googled deep to the bottom of the internet and can't find any info about the possibility to fire some event after a product is added via API to reload the mini-cart contents. Anyone can help me with this issue and point to the right direction?

Add to cart function, works as expected

```
function addToCart() {
        console.log("add-to-cart");
        apiFetch({
            path: "/wc/store/v1/cart/add-item",
            method: "POST",
            data: {
                id: 79,
                quantity: 1
            },
            headers: {
                Nonce: window.vars.nonce,
            },
        }).then((res) => {
            console.log(res);
        });
    }
```

Comment: Tried something simple like https://stackoverflow.com/a/50582809/1427878 ?

Comment: @CBroe, hi! Yes tried, but as I understood the StoreAPI and block mini-cart are not related to cart-fragments. So refreshing the fragments like this gives only results if using the classic theme like Storefront and mini-cart widget based on cart fragments.

Comment: Run second function in addToCart where apiFetch({ path: "/wc/store/v1/cart", method: "GET")  should update the cart and from there run 3rd function to populate the data from the cart into your mini-cart.

Comment: @Snuffy thanx! I tried this approach and made 2nd function to fetch the cart, but I really don't know how to populate the mini-cart. BTW, this is a woocommerce mini-cart block, not custom-made by me.